# Rails activerecord: combine two query on same table with where and in

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am doing following two queries and it gives output properly as I expect.

```
 a = Application.where("prio1 = ? and initially_selected =?", true, true).pluck(:registration_id)
Application.where("prio3 = ? and registration_id not in (?)", true, a)
```

But I think there is a better way to perform the query in one single line. So I tried this

```
Application.where("prio3 = ? and NOT (prio1 = ? and initially_selected =?)", true, true, true)
```

This last query doesn't give me correct output. What am I missing here? or How can I combine first two query above to one query?

Comment: Hmm. Please be more precise about what happens vs. what you would expect to happen.

Comment: The only thing I can see is a missing space before the last question mark. What do you get when you call `to_sql` on the query? Does that look good?

Comment: did you miss second part of the second query?

Comment: Here's a tip, don't use `pluck(:registration_id)` as it will trigger the query and immediately return the IDs array. Instead, use `select(:registration_id)` as it will return an ActiveRecord_Relation which, when passed to another query will result in all work being done on the DB side reducing your round-trips.